# eeprom : uevent generated infinite times in linux kernel 4.4.0

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, udev

I am using Ubuntu 16.0.4 running with linux kernel 4.4.0. I have couple of EEPROMS over i2c adaptor connected on my board.
When I insert the `eeprom` module, I see indefinite `uevent` messages in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.153601] eeprom 23-0056: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.153664] eeprom 19-0050: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.153725] eeprom 19-0050: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.153787] eeprom 23-0054: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.153852] eeprom 12-0050: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.153914] eeprom 23-0056: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.153976] eeprom 23-0056: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154041] eeprom 12-0050: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154103] eeprom 23-0056: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154166] eeprom 19-0050: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154227] eeprom 19-0050: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154292] eeprom 23-0054: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154357] eeprom 12-0050: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154419] eeprom 23-0056: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154482] eeprom 23-0056: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154547] eeprom 12-0050: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154609] eeprom 23-0056: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154671] eeprom 19-0050: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154732] eeprom 19-0050: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154806] eeprom 23-0054: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154871] eeprom 12-0050: uevent
Jul 28 15:07:16 manik kernel: [15801.154934] eeprom 23-0056: uevent
```

I checked the sysfs device tree and device nodes for all the eeproms chips are created fine.

I don't understand why the uevents for EEPROM chips are still being generated.

Anyone know why ?

Comment: http://lists.openwall.net/linux-kernel/2016/03/23/386

Comment: @AndyShevchenko somewhow I missed your comment. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled i2c-core debugging(`CONFIG_I2C_DEBUG_CORE` not set) in kernel configuration.